# How to get travis to clone git SSH URLs?

Tags: git, travis-ci

Specifying a `git` SSH URL as a submodule causes `travis-c` to fail at cloning. See [a log of a failing Orienteer build](https://travis-ci.org/PhantomYdn/Orienteer/builds/55963121) as example. Is there any way to get `travis-ci` to clone such repositories?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a problem on `travis-ci` but you try to clone a private repo without the read right.

See http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/private-dependencies/ to use an ssh key to clone your private repo.

Update :
You can see help from github to cloning a ssh repo : https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use/#cloning-with-ssh